# Thread only receiving Data on Debug mode

Tags: multithreading, delphi, indy, indy10

This is a reading Thread for an incoming `IdTCPClient` connection in `Delphi`.

```
unit UnitWorkerThread;

interface

uses
    System.Classes,
    IdTCPClient;

type
    TDataEvent = procedure(const Data: Byte) of object;

    TReadingThread = class(TThread)
    private
        FClient: TIdTCPClient;
        FData  : Byte;
        FOnData: TDataEvent;
        procedure DataReceived;
    protected
        procedure Execute; override;
    public
        constructor Create(AClient: TIdTCPClient); reintroduce;
        property OnData: TDataEvent read FOnData write FOnData;
    end;

implementation

constructor TReadingThread.Create(AClient: TIdTCPClient);
begin
    inherited Create(True);
    FClient := AClient;
end;

procedure TReadingThread.Execute;
begin
    while not Terminated do
    begin
        FData := FClient.IOHandler.ReadByte;
        if Assigned(FOnData) then
            Synchronize(DataReceived);
    end;
end;

procedure TReadingThread.DataReceived;
begin
    if Assigned(FOnData) then
        FOnData(FData);
end;

end.
```

And this is how I'm creating and dealing with it on my `Form`.

```
procedure TFormLogin.IdTCPClient1Connected(Sender: TObject);
var

    Thread  : TReadingThread;

begin

    try
        Thread        := TReadingThread.Create(IdTCPClient1);
        Thread.OnData := DataReceived;
        Thread.Start;

    except
    end;

end;

procedure TFormLogin.DataReceived(const Data: Byte);
begin
        FormHome.ModbusClient1.PutRxData(Data);
end;
```

I can't get to understand *why* it only **receive Data** when *debugging step-by-step*.

What could possibly be causing it?

Comment: How exactly it doesn't work: it hangs (deadlocks) or gives incorrect data or raises exception? And what do you mean by 'debugging': is it stepping over lines of code you showed, or merely enabling debugging and/or using debug dcu's in project options? I think, you should also show the code when you create instance of thread object, assigning event and resuming it.

Comment: I mean stepping over the lines. It won't raise any exception nor even receive any incoming Data. I'll update the question with the details.

Comment: First of all, get rid of try-except block hiding exceptions: they can be quite informative. It would be also great to implement onTerminate event and check there is FatalException <> nil. If so, show Exception(FatalException).message - in this case you will see what happened in your thread (otherwise it just 'breaks' silently, maybe that's exactly what's happening)

Comment: There are no exceptions being generated without the try-except block.

Comment: The `TidTCPServer` (and may be the `TidTCPClient`) create threads for their work. I had a [question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/31020880/5043424) that was closed when this was discovered. It seems that your thread creates a dependant secondary `TidTCPClient` thread and thus causes the described problems. In other words the `TReadingThread` instance and its `FClient` are working in separate threads.

Comment: You appear to have posted the code after you've hacked it around using trial and error methods. Can you post a [mcve]?

Comment: You don't keep a reference to the thread, and it is not created with `FreeOnTerminate` property set to true. This means that it will be difficult to terminate the thread properly.

Comment: No exceptions in try-except block was expected, your error probably happens in TReadingThread, you can catch it only with FatalException check in onTerminate event. BTW, multithreaded app working when debugging line by line but failing in normal operation is pretty common, it's obvious clue that race condition occurs, say, your TCP client must finish handling TCPClient1Connected event before reading bytes, so while you are debugging it all completes and then byte is read normally, but otherwise thread begins executing immediately!

Comment: Is it possible to identify when `TCPClient` has finished handling `TCPClientConnect` event? It looks like it could be it.

Comment: You can try checking FClient.Connected inside your Execute method, but I'm not sure it's the case after all, need to look at Indy source code. But anyway, exceptions my occur in any network operation and your program should 'be ready' for it and inform user what happened.

Comment: @Holmes: Create the thread after `TIdTCPClient.Connect()` has exited, or at least in the `TIdTCPClient.OnConnected` event.

Comment: @YuriyAfanasenkov: checking `Connected()` is a bad idea, especially if the problem is timing related to reading too soon. `Connected()` performs a read operation internally.

Comment: @RemyLebeau but the Thread is already being created inside `TIdTCPClient.OnConnected` event

Comment: @Holmes: you asked ”*Is it possible to identify when TCPClient has finished handling TCPClientConnect event?*". `OnConnected` is triggered immediately after the socket is connected to the server and just before `Connect()` exits. So, how to know `OnConnected` has finished? When `Connect()` has exited. Which is another viable time to create the thread, since Indy clients are not event driven.

Comment: Given the code shown, the only way this code would not work is if either the server is not sending data to begin with, or more likely your main thread is being blocked from processing `Synchronize()` requests by code that has not been shown yet.  Where is the code that is calling `Connect()`? Where is the code that ks processing `PutRxData()`? What else is your code doing while the client is running?

Comment: I'll still be doing some tests to verify it before posting it as an answer, but it looks like the problem was all about `TReadingThread` being used as a local variable. Additionally, I would like to say a great thanks because you guys helped me to understand a lot better about how it works under the hood.

Comment: That doesn't make sense? TReadingThread being a local or global variable shouldn't change anything in what you've posted.

Comment: @LievenKeersmaekers I agree, that doesn't make sense to me either. I'm trying to understand what made this behaviour so I can post a decent answer.